# Python Speechrecognizer

Tags: python, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I'm currently working on my own voice assistant, but I often times have the problem that it's taking very long to answer/recognize that I'm not sayin anything.
I already tried using:

```
listener.energy_threshold = 120
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    listener.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source,duration=1)
```

but it didn't seem to help.

My listener function:

```
def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice, language="de")
            command = command.lower()
    except:
        print("failed")
    return command
```

Oftentimes the assistant takes a minute or more to answer.

Comment: do you use `energy_threshold` and other options inside `take_command`?

Comment: maybe you should print exceptions to see what can make problems - `except Exception as ex: print(ex)`

Comment: do you have fast connection to internet? It has to send your voice to Google's server in USA and get result from this server.

Comment: 1. The listener funtion i send, is the one I'm currently using I tried slight alterations but I don't quite recall what those changes were.
2.  I don't get the exeption case that often, it just takes a long time to recognize that I'm not talking anymore.
3. My internet connection usually shouldn't be a problem I'm connected to the Internet via lan with 50k Mbit/s